# dynamic naming of fields in nsmutable array?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, nsmutablearray

I hope i can explain this clearly. 
I have a `NSMutableArray * myMut.`
I have user input in the form of an `NSString * anyoldString.`
I have user input of some numeric values stored in the variable someNumber;

As users input their string and values, I want to update `myMut`, and name the fields `anyoldString`

like this: `myMut.anyoldString=someNumber;`
depending on the user's input, the name will be different of course

i'm new to objective c.

in **Matlab**, I would do this:

```
myMut.(anyoldString)=someNumer.
```

I know that's too easy for objective c! but any fast way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to do something like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myMutableDictionary; // A mutable **dictionary**, not an array!
NSInteger someNumber; // filled by the number
NSString *key; // filled by anyOldString

[myMutableDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:someNumber] forKey:key];
```

`NSArray` and friends aren't associative; but indexed. What you want is `NSDictionary` and friends; your friendly neighborhood key-value mapping!

**Edit:** For funsies; getting someNumber back out, given anyOldString:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myMutableDictionary; // The same dictionary as above
NSInteger someNumber; // out number
NSString *key; // filled by anyOldString

NSNumber *storedNumber = [myMutableDictionary objectForKey:key];

if (storedNumber) {
  someNumber = [storedNumber integerValue];
} else {
  someNumber = APPLICATION_APPROPRIATE_DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: this sounds so good i'm almost willing to check it before i try it out. thanks! never knew about nsdictionaries! it seems that i can add any object to the dictionary. does it work even if the objects added are of different classes?